# Extract Row Groups Based on Condition

Tags: r

Using the `officer` package, I have extracted the text of a word document. A small example of my problem is below:

```
df <- data.frame(style_name = c("heading 1", "para 1", "para 1", "para 1", "heading 1", "para 1", "para 1", "heading 1", "para 1", "heading 1", "para 1"),
             text = c("Introduction", "Some", "Intro", "Wording", "Background", "Some more", "wording to suit", "Another heading", "and paragraph wording", "Final Heading", "Closing words go here"))
```

Which returns the following:

```
   style_name                  text
1   heading 1          Introduction
2      para 1                  Some
3      para 1                 Intro
4      para 1               Wording
5   heading 1            Background
6      para 1             Some more
7      para 1       wording to suit
8   heading 1       Another heading
9      para 1 and paragraph wording
10  heading 1         Final Heading
11     para 1 Closing words go here
```

I want to extract text from each section (row groups) from `heading 1` to the row before the next `heading 1` - essentially including the heading name and last paragraph of each section.

An ideal approach would be to assign a section_group number to each section of text and then use filtering to manipulate for my requirements.

The desired output would be:

```
   style_name                  text section_group
1   heading 1          Introduction             1
2      para 1                  Some             1
3      para 1                 Intro             1
4      para 1               Wording             1
5   heading 1            Background             2
6      para 1             Some more             2
7      para 1       wording to suit             2
8   heading 1       Another heading             3
9      para 1 and paragraph wording             3
10  heading 1         Final Heading             4
11     para 1 Closing words go here             4
```

Comment: try ```df%>%mutate(section_group=cumsum(style_name=="heading 1"))```

Comment: Thank you - great simple approach that works!